# Can't find bundle even if the files are present

Tags: jasperserver

I have added 3 resource bundles for the languages english, french and portugese. I have added these in WEB-INF/bundles path. I have used `$R{}` for the all the labels in my report. I haven't added any resource bundles in the *JasperReports Server* repository.

My understanding was that, since I have used `$R` for my labels, *JasperReports Server* first checks within the report and repository if the relevant .properties file is present and once found will do the translation. If not found it will search in WEB-INF/bundles.

Since, I have not added the .properties files in report or repository , it must search in WEB-INF/bundles.

But, when I run the report I get the error

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name language, locale en_US
```

Any ideas on this would of great help

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Had to put the files in WEB-INF/classes instead of WEB-INF/bundles

Thanks

Comment: can we use the property in the report without mentioning the location of the ResourceBundle ?

Comment: I have created properties file in WEB-INF/classes folder, but the property is not being returned as null in my report.